# how to select many items from datagrid with click instead of control click?

Tags: winforms, datagridview

In order to select many item from Data Grid the user should use the control button.
How can I change it click-only without the need of the control?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? What is the 'control button'? You mean select cells/rows by code when you click on a button? what have you tried? Which language are you using C# VB.Net...?

Comment: do not use click to select row .. your dgv have purposes with it ..

Comment: Chris, I meant the control button in the keyboard. Without the control when clicking on the second item (a row from the gatagrid in my case) - it cancels the selection of the first selected item. I'm using c#. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+ MouseClick for selecting multiple fields is functionality that works across all Microsoft products.  Do you really want to change MS functionality for your app?  The reason I ask is that it could lead to user confusion.

Comment: This indeed is an important point. But still in my specific case the answer is yes because the UI I'm creating is destinated mainly for children- therefore the way to select the items is quite sighnificant, and selecting it by click only is definitely the preferred way. thanks!